# Java thread hangs after CompletionService.take()

Tags: java, service, executor, completion, take

I've got simple test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletionService<Integer> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    cs.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        public Integer call(){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(3000); // Just sleep and print
                System.out.println("Sleeping thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 10;
        }
    });
    try{
        Future<Integer> fi = cs.take();
        System.out.println(fi.get());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I run it, sleep 3 seconds, and prints

```
Sleeping thread: 14
10
```

But then it hangs there, the program doesn't end.

What's happening, how to make it finish?

Comment: The thread in your executor is a user thread, not a daemon thread, so the JVM won't exit until it times out (60 seconds by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by [tgdavies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11002/tgdavies), your program will exit after +/- 60 seconds, because that is the default timeout for a thread without tasks in an `ExecutorService` created by [`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()).

If you don't want to wait for 60 seconds, you should shutdown the executor service after you're done submitting tasks.

For example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    try {
        CompletionService<Integer> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
        cs.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
            public Integer call() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000); // Just sleep and print
                    System.out.println("Sleeping thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return 10;
            }
        });
        try {
            Future<Integer> fi = cs.take();
            System.out.println(fi.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, configure the executor service to create daemon threads using a custom `ThreadFactory`. Only do this if it is not a problem that an executor service that is doing actual work gets "killed" when there are no more normal (non-daemon) threads.